# Как в Kotlin случайным образом выбрать 1 значение в каждом столбце двумерного массива?

Tags: kotlin

Как в **Kotlin** случайным образом выбрать 1 значение в каждом столбце двумерного массива и результат записать в новый массив?

**Дано:**

```
val table = Array(3, { Array(3, {0}) })
table[0] = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)     // первая строка таблицы
table[1] = arrayOf(4, 5, 6)     // вторая строка таблицы
table[2] = arrayOf(7, 8, 9)     // третья строка таблицы
```

**Вывод** должен быть, к примеру, таким: **1, 8, 6**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `Random`.

Вот пример программы :)

```
import kotlin.random.Random

fun main() {
    val table = Array(3) { Array(3) { 0 } }
    table[0] = arrayOf(1, 2, 3)     // первая строка таблицы
    table[1] = arrayOf(4, 5, 6)     // вторая строка таблицы
    table[2] = arrayOf(7, 8, 9)     // третья строка таблицы

    val numRows = table.size
    val numCols = table[0].size

    val resultArray = Array(numCols) { 0 }

    for (col in 0 until numCols) {
        val randomRow = Random.nextInt(numRows)
        resultArray[col] = table[randomRow][col]
    }

    println("Случайные значения из каждого столбца:")
    println(resultArray.joinToString(", "))
}
```

В примере, код создает новый массив `resultArray` и заполняет его случайными значениями из каждого столбца исходного массива `table`. Размер нового массива соответствует количеству столбцов исходного массива.

Answer (score 0):

Основываясь на решении с элементами типа **Int** попробовал решить задачу, в которой элементы типа **String**

```
table[0] = arrayOf("A", "B", "C")
table[1] = arrayOf("D", "E", "F")
table[2] = arrayOf("G", "J", "I")
```

Для решения этой задачи пришлось внести изменения в две строки:

```
val table: Array<Array<String>> = Array(3) {Array(3) {""} }
val resultArray = Array(numCols) { "" }
```